# Three men: One dead

Tags: logical-deduction

## Three Men: One Dead

The story goes like this:

**Three men** walked into a forest, but only **two men** survived. One of them was found next to a tree, and had major memory loss, and other one was badly injured by a bear. As for the last one, a bullet wound was found in him.

They let the two men go after being hospitalized, but the last man went missing before they could inspect him.

## So, what do we know?

We know the following facts:

Kept in spoilers so you can make it harder.

> A gunshot was heard, then lots of bear noises were heard. This was reported by the lady  who found the men. The lady also had major hearing problems.

> The one with memory loss **actually** did have memory loss. The whole thing was, he remembered everything except going into the forest.

> None of them had a gun on them, making the story mysterious.

> The man attacked by a bear was shocked, and only said one thing, "The bullet, the bear, the gun." After a bit, he said that they got into an argument before a bear jumped at him and he ran.

## Hints:

> The man attacked by a bear was attacked before he heard the gunshot.

> The lady might have been incorrect..

> It can't be the one who had memory loss, right?

> Is it me, or is the man who got attacked by the bear contradicting his story?

## Solve it:

To solve it you must:

State the order in which it happened. Put the man who was actually the killer in a spoiler. Give reasoning as to why you think that.

Answers close the actual answer will get a comment telling them something along the lines of "very close".

## My First Puzzle

Note: This is my first puzzle, and I am still learning to ask them correctly. Point out any mistakes, and I'll gladly fix them!

Comment: We strongly prefer for puzzles to be [uniquely solvable with only visible content](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5019/69582); I understand what you're trying to do by hiding successive pieces of information but I recommend you reconsider that.

Comment: @bobble Thank you for the recommendation! I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The killer is

> The dead man with a bullet wound. Yes, it is a suicide.

Assumption

> Since "None of them had a gun on them" does not specifically state when this fact apply. So, I will assume that **when the three men were found, none of them had a gun on them.**

What happened

> Three men walked into a forest. One of them had a gun. (The man that is going to suicide)

> The man tried to suicide in front of the other two men, but the two men try to stop him. So, they got into an argument.

> The suicidal man succeeded to shoot himself, which caused a loud gunshot. One of them was shocked by the scene and fainted next to a tree. The other man went to take the gun.

> (At the same time, but in different places) A lady heard a gunshot. A bear heard a gunshot.

> [Hearing a load gunshot, the bear was quickly attracted to the origin of the sound.](https://www.nrahlf.org/articles/2018/11/13/does-a-hunter-s-gunshot-attract-predators/) When the bear came to the scene and found the only person standing there, it suddenly attacked the man.

> The lady heard lots of bear noises. The lady then slowly went to the direction of the origin of the sound. The lady was being careful because those sounds were dangerous (gunshot and bear), but she thought there might be people who are in trouble that she could help.

> The man was badly injured by the bear and ran for his life, dropping the gun. The man was so shocked that he could only say "The bullet, the bear, the gun.".

> The bear didn't continue to chase the man, and it went into the forest.

> The lady found the injured man, and the other two not so far away from the spot.

> The gun was not found at this point. So, it is safe to say "None of them had a gun on them".

Comment: Well done! That was pretty quick!

Answer (score 1):

I think the killer is

> The lady

Why?

> The lady might be a hunter as people who hunt without the right ear protection tend to have hearing problems.

> The bear to attack the human but the lady tried to hunt the bear but missed and hit one of the people.

> also since none of the men had any gun the lady is the last suspect.

Comment: Nice way about thinking about this! I never thought about anyone picking the lady!